# making a require line in javascript using visual studio code

Tags: javascript

I'm starting to learn javascript and I want to organize my code with folders, but when I used `` require(`./fileName`) `` but it didn't work. help?

Comment: Require is not like an `include` in C or C++. You have to assign the result of require to a variable.

Comment: More information is required, for starters, your folder structure and error messages. What do you mean by `it didn't` work? The more information you give the better.

Comment: How does the structure of your folders look like?